# Why is there no duplication when using offset limit in querydsl fetchjoin statement?

Tags: spring, jpa, join, fetch, querydsl

**Classes**

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Classes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String className;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classes", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Teacher> teachers;

    @Builder
    public Classes(String className, List<Teacher> teachers) {
        this.className = className;
        this.teachers = teachers;
    }

    public void updateTeachers(List<Teacher> teachers) {
        teachers.forEach(teacher -> teacher.updateClasses(this));
        this.teachers = teachers;
    }
}
```

**Teacher**

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Integer age;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classes_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Classes classes;

    @Builder
    public Teacher(String name, Integer age, Classes classes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    public void updateClasses(Classes classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }
}
```

**ClassesQueryDsl**

```
public class ClassesCustomRepositoryImpl extends QuerydslRepositorySupport implements ClassesCustomRepository  {

    

    @Override
    public List<Classes> findAllNoPageFetchJoin() {
        return from(classes)
                .leftJoin(classes.teachers).fetchJoin()
                .fetch();
    }

    
}
```

**Test Code**

```
@Test
void findAllNoPageFetchJoin() {
    // given
    List<InputRequest.TeacherRequest> teacherRequests = List.of(InputRequest.TeacherRequest.builder()
                    .age(12)
                    .name("name")
                    .build(), InputRequest.TeacherRequest.builder()
                    .age(23)
                    .name("name2")
                    .build(),
            InputRequest.TeacherRequest.builder()
                    .age(41)
                    .name("wedul")
                    .build()
    );

    List<InputRequest.TeacherRequest> teacherRequests2 = List.of(InputRequest.TeacherRequest.builder()
                    .age(22)
                    .name("name4")
                    .build(), InputRequest.TeacherRequest.builder()
                    .age(33)
                    .name("name5")
                    .build(),
            InputRequest.TeacherRequest.builder()
                    .age(44)
                    .name("name6")
                    .build()
    );

    // when
    sut.insert(InputRequest.builder()
            .className("1")
            .teacherRequestList(teacherRequests)
            .build());
    sut.insert(InputRequest.builder()
            .className("2")
            .teacherRequestList(teacherRequests2)
            .build());

    // then
    List<Classes> savedData = classesRepository.findAllNoPageFetchJoin();

    assertThat(savedData).hasSize(6);
}
```

[result count image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfKbL.png)

An entity has a oneToMany relationship between classes and teachers.

When bringing classes using querydsl, duplicate classes are brought as many as the number of teachers.

**[result]**

- class id : 1,  List<> teach id : 1,2,3
- class id : 1,  List<> teach id : 1,2,3
- class id : 1,  List<> teach id : 1,2,3
- class id : 2,  List<> teach id : 4,5,6
- class id : 2,  List<> teach id : 4,5,6
- class id : 2,  List<> teach id : 4,5,6

However, if only the offset limit is attached to the same querydsl statement, the value is not duplicated.

Rows with the same class id are not paginated as much as the number of teach, but classes with duplicates removed are paginated and exposed.

**QueryDsl**

```
@Override
public List<Classes> findAllPageFetchJoin(int offset, int limit) {
    return from(classes)
            .leftJoin(classes.teachers).fetchJoin()
            .offset(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .fetch();
}
```

[result count image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l79K9.png)

**[result]**

- class id : 1, List<> : teach id : 1,2,3
- class id : 2, List<> : teach id : 4,5,6

I know that the application handles paging when I do offset limit in fetch join, but I don't know why duplicates became distinct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it was written in Korean, I found the cause and wrote the reason on the blog. It's written in code, so I think you can understand it. I hope this will be answered if you have similar questions.
https://wedul.tistory.com/716

Comment: Pretty sure the fetch join is ignored after the offset / limit are applied.

Comment: Offset and limit really mess with 1:M joins. Check out the SQL that is generated, but the net take away is to not use them together - try to use some form of batch fetching instead ( see https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.0-M3/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#BATCH for an example in EclipseLink)